# Why do so many kids in Digimon wear gloves?

Tags: clothing, digimon

In the first season of *Digimon*, five of the eight kids wear gloves (Sora on the far left wears them, but they are not visible in this picture). This is despite them wearing summer camp clothes when they first go to the Digital World.

[image: Digimon Season 1 Characters]

The second season has three out of six wearing gloves (although Kari's gloves are really just part of her shirt).

[image: Digimon Season 2 Characters]

Why is it that so many protagonists wear gloves? Has this ever been explained, either in-universe or out-of-universe?

Comment: Because drawing hands is hard

Comment: Also note that the two youngest in the first season (kneeling in front) are the same two kids in the back of the shot of the second season, not wearing gloves either time. So it's 7 glove-wearers to 5 bare-handers.

Comment: [They also seem to have stopped wearing gloves by highschool](https://snapthirty.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/digimon-adventure-tri-screenshot-01.jpg)

Comment: Gloves make your stronger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pure speculation - based on similar choices in other IPs - but I assume the most probable reason is artistic choice due to visibility:

- Gloves allow for higher contrast between hands, forearms, and faces. This can be especially important for characters with short sleeves on their shirts.
- Gloves make it possible to increase the size and detail of hands giving the artists more leeway without making their characters into Popeyes.

Both *Super Mario* and *Sonic* would be typical examples for this where you'd have a hard time seeing their hands and fingers while them also bring too small.

Comment: Fair point about contrast with hands, especially for those who are short sleeved. For the gloveless kids in Season 1, T.K. is the only one wearing long sleeves and Joe has colored bracelets. Only Kari lacks either affordance, but she came in partway through the series, so maybe the artists had more practice by that point and didn't need that. In Season 2, everybody wears long sleeves.